# what does "flat clutch of the season" mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

what does "flat clutch of the season" mean in the following passage?

> From that Dutch period they might draw a line across the breastbone, revealing only upper neck and shoulders as the slender gown fell to the feet, where pads of velvet on the instep finished off the shoes.
>
> The show opened with shorter dresses, in black and ink blue, dense lace collars giving them an ecclesiastical feel and a single plait of hair falling downward. And surely only this couple could show the **flat clutch of the season** and make it seem like a religious book.

(Source: The International Herald Tribune, March 7 2013, article: Stillness and grace)

Comment: Please provide the source.

Comment: Hint: try searching for clutch handbag.

Comment: cambridge has https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clutch#:~:text=a%20small%20bag%20with%20no%20handle%20or%20strap%2C%20used%20esp.%20by%20women%20for%20carrying%20small%20personal%20items

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is discussing fashion.  Based on a fashion context, a "clutch" would be a style for a woman's purse or handbag.

From Merriam Webster for "clutch bag"

```
a woman's small usually strapless handbag
```